# Store range of strings in array (vba)

Tags: string, vba, range

The goal is to create an array with the items in the declared range. Simple but I can't get it to work...

```
'Declaration
Dim Measures As Variant
Dim MeasureRows As Long

'Search and store
Sheets(4).Activate
MeasureRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Measures = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(MeasureRows, 1)).Value2
```

MeasureRows populates fine but when I go to check Measures, it is empty. e.g.

```
?MeasureRows
 780 
?Measures(MeasureRows) 'Returns "Subscript out of range"    
?Measures(1) 'Returns "Subscript out of range"
```

I'm very green when in comes to VBA so please excuse the basic question. I tried searching the web for answers but I couldn't get anything to work. I imagine I just don't know the right jargon for the search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 2 dimensional when read from sheet

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim Measures As Variant
    Dim MeasureRows As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        MeasureRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Measures = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(MeasureRows, 1)).Value2
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Measures, 1) To UBound(Measures, 1)
        Debug.Print Measures(i, 1)
    Next
    Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: You may also need MeasureRows -1

Comment: Great. Thank you. I see you have it s/t it prints every item of Measures after it has been populated. Is there a way to see my array in a place similar to the Matlab Workspace or the R Environment?

Comment: You can inspect it in the locals window when it stops at the STOP command. You want to delete that command at a later point.